# JQuery modifying child window in Firefox and .ready()

Tags: jquery

I know there are a zillion posts here about opening a child window and accessing/modifying the DOM and I think I've read them all but still can't get it to work. This works in IE:

```
// Find element with id="main_title" in child window and set its content to "2"
function generateRecipe () {
  var windowSize = "width=1300,height=1100,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes";
  var win = window.open("template_without_img.html", "displayWindow", windowSize);
  $(win.document).ready(function () {
    $(win.document).contents().find('#main_title').html('2');
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work in Firefox 16. Why? I tried many different variations including putting code at the bottom of the child window to access values in the parent window.

I finally did find one thing that worked in Firefox 16:

```
var win;
function generateRecipe () {
  var windowSize = "width=1300,height=1100,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes";
  win = window.open("template_without_img.html", "displayWindow", windowSize);
  setTimeout(continueExecution, 1000);
}

function continueExecution() {
  $(win.document).contents().find('#main_title').html('2');
}
```

I can certainly do this but I'm still learning JQuery and want to start out doing these things the right way instead of relying on hacks.

Firefox error console says this:

Error: gBrowser.addProgressListener was called with a second argument, which is not supported. See bug 608628.

So is this some kind of bug in Firefox 16? Does it have something to do with security (both parent and child HTML files are on my machine)? Or am I just doing something wrong?

More info. Found something else that works in Firefox but unfortunately it doesn't work in IE. Using $(win).load() instead of $(win.document).ready():

```
function generateRecipe () {
  var windowSize = "width=1300,height=1100,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes";
  win = window.open("template_without_img.html", "displayWindow", windowSize);
  $(win).load(function() {
    $(win.document).contents().find('#main_title').html('2');
  });
}
```

This is so confusing. I wish I knew what was going on. Does ready() simply not work right in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML

```
$(win.document).contents().find('#main_title').innerHTML('2');
```

Comment: innerHTML is not a function. I also tried innerHTML = '2' but that doesn't work either (in IE or Firefox)

Comment: Is more than one main_title tag? .HTML() only works with the first element found.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var win = window.open('', 'window', '', '');
var txt = document.getElementById("main_title").innerHTML;
win.document.open();
win.document.write(''+ txt + '');
win.document.close();
```